# Awkward Guests: What to do if you don't have enough points to buy an offer?

Tags: untagged

The rules say you must pay the amount of the offer or more, but doesn't specify what to do if you can't buy any offer. You just stay without an interchange that round?

Comment: Is awkward guests a game?

Comment: http://www.awkwardguests.com/

Comment: I didn't find the tag, I guess it's not famous on this site?

Comment: I was wanting to confirm the game before I added the tag. It isn't a tag because this is the first question asked about it and tags only exists for things that have had questions asked about before.

Comment: Its a very good game as well!  Imagine Cluedo as a trading game rather than roll and move.  https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/188866/awkward-guests

Comment: The bad part is the setup time... It's 45 minutes to play, but 45 minutes to setup and 15 minutes to store it back - But the fact that we play is testament that it's actually good. I don't know if people would spend 45 minutes preparing a Monopoly board :-D

Comment: How is it taking 45 mins?    When packing away the cards we give 1 player 0-99 another 100-199 and so on to sort.   As long as you keep cards in order it shouldn’t take to long to set up.

Comment: Maybe I'm exaggerating a bit, but we usually play a 2 person game and the other person's a child, so it certainly takes 20 minutes at least. Also, we use the app to generate games and you can't see ALL cards at the same time on the app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

from the rules [here](http://www.awkwardguests.com/docs/AG_Rulebook_ver04.pdf)

> Once all non-active players have made their offers, the active player
> decides who to exchange cards with. They MAY EXCHANGE CARDS WITH AS
> MANY PLAYERS AS THEY PLEASE. The active player must give each chosen
> player cards from their hand (regardless of their references) that sum
> up a total amount of information points EQUAL TO OR GREATER THAN the
> amount that was offered. Exchanges are always for the TOTAL
> information points offered. It is NOT ALLOWED to negotiate for a
> fraction of the amount. Exchanges are done all at once and players add
> the cards received to their hands. Once all exchanges have been
> completed, it will be the next player’s turn.

The key part of this to answer your question is "the active player decides who to exchange cards with". So you can decide no one. If you can not afford any offer are forced to pick no one. so if 'all exchanges completed' total zero then it's the next players turn.

It's quite possible you might decide not to accept an offer as you suspect a player is trying to pass you back cards you have already seen.

You may still get the chance to exchange cards by making offers to other players during their turn.